# WP7 help with menu effects

Tags: silverlight, xaml, menu, windows-phone-7, effects

Kinda new to Silverlight and have some experience with WPF but I'm doing a project with a group for a class making a game for WP7. I am currently in charge of the menu system for the game and I had a few ideas for "flashy" menu transitions. I got some going for the main menu but I wanted to do something cool for the options submenu.

Anyway my idea is to either fashion an expander or to have sort of a variation of a dialog box. But the way I envisioned it would be in either case the menu items blur but are still visible while the expanded menu is displayed or while the dialog is active. If I'm being confusing sorry :) but think of Windows 7 glass effect on the menu while other options are available.

What I'm getting at is I want to give this a shot but I have no idea how I would go about doing something like this. Could anyone point me in the right direction or outline some key steps for me to build off?

I tried finding something like this on Google but no such luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at the many items available in the Education Catalog over on the AppHub - http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/?contenttype=0&devarea=65&platform=54&sort=1